# Contacting team@stackoverflow for disown questions request

Tags: support

I would like to disown some of my questions from my profile, this answer indicates that contacting the staff is the only way:

[Question disowned by author/moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127466/question-disowned-by-author-moderator?lq=1)

I have sent an email to team@stackexchange, and when I didn't get any reply, I sent another email to team@stackoverflow requesting the disown.

But I haven't got any reply. What should I do?
Please note, I am very sorry that I have to send an email for this, but it seems to me that this is the only option available (I also think that trusted users, say with more than 15k, should have the possibility to disown a question without resorting to send an email).

Note: I didn't include `.com` in the text for the emails to avoid email scrapers.

### Edit:

More than 1 month has passed without replies.

### Edit3:

After a staff member (@tim) contacted me, nothing changed since then.

Comment: When did you send it? Keep in mind that they are usually pretty busy and a response might take a while.

Comment: That's a pretty short delay. For proper handling you should allow six to eight weeks.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I can't tell if you're being sarcastic.

Comment: @dynamic [I doubt that was serious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)

Comment: @remyabel, only half-way. The questioner does have to wait a little more for their request to be taken into account. I don't have hard numbers, so I went with Jeff's approach to the problem.

Comment: I don't email the team often, but I did it once and it took 9 days to get a response (Sep 17th with a reply on Sep 26th).  You just need to be patient.

Comment: Expecting an answer within 2-3 days for a non-urgent issue on a site with this volume of users is pretty unrealistic. It's not like someone is going to suffer great injury if they don't drop everything to get to this for you. Have some patience, and keep in mind you're not the only user here who emailed them.

Comment: @KenWhite: more than 1 month has passed since my first email. Is this a normal wait period?

Comment: I don't know what is *normal*, as I'm not part of the SE team. I'd follow up with another email to them. Remember though that disassociating questions from your account is not going to be a high priority task for them.

Comment: Sure I understand that, for me it is not a problem to wait. The problem is that I don't know if they have received that email or they simply missed it

Comment: Well, following up with another email as I suggested would make sure they didn't *just miss it*, wouldn't it?

Comment: Stupid question: you did include `.com` in the address you sent to, right?

Comment: Maybe @Frederic wasn't joking...

Comment: Out of interest, which questions do you want to disown? And why?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry that this fell through the cracks, I've contacted you privately to get this taken care of. I blame the holidays.

Comment: Hi Tim, is there anything else that you need to complete my request? Thanks